# Filezilla regex for filtering out all subdir except one

Tags: regex, filezilla, posix

I'm trying to get filezilla filtering out all the subfolder of a certain folder except one without success. My tree looks like this:

```
css/
  |--many files and dirs...
js/
  |--many files and dirs...
script/
  |--dist/
       |--many files and dirs...
  |--less/
       |---many files and dirs...
  |--fonts/
       |---many files and dirs...
  |--Gruntfile.js
  |--something.json
  |--many other files...
index.html
```

and I want it to become:

```
css/
  |--many files and dirs...
js/
  |--many files and dirs...
script/
  |--dist/
       |--many files and dirs...
index.html
```

I found that this regex works in theory: `folder\/(?!sub1)[\/a-zA-Z]+` but Filezilla supports only POSIX extended regular expressions and this does not work.

**EDIT**

In Filezilla for creating a filter go to

```
View > Filename filters... > Edit filter rules... > New
```

Clearly if someone can get the result without using regex but with the predefined conditions of Filezilla is the same for me

Comment: I'm trying to test this but while I am quite familiar with regexes, I am less so with filezilla. Could you explain where exactly you are using this regex so I can play with it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Filezilla works but the `(?!sub1)` construct is a negative lookbehind meaning "match only if the previous word is not `sub1`. POSIX EREs do not support lookarounds so you need to use a different approach. For example, you could set up a filter using the "Filter out any items matching any of the following" and use this regex:

```
.*sub[2-9].*
```

That means "match any character, then `sub` followed by any number between 2 and 9, then any character again. That will filter out all the unwanted `sub` folders. Note that that regex will also exclude `sub11`, I don't know if that's an issue for you.

If your actual directory names are different, you'll need a different approach. In that case, please edit your question and include the real file and directory names.

Comment: sorry, I should have written that names of files and folder were only examples

Comment: @Red yes, I kind of thought they were. The main point here is that ERE don't do lookarounds. That means you'll need something more specific to your data. You could also do something completely different and just set remove read permissions from the directories you don't want.